# Is it possible to get 3 specific randoms in specific order in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

The task asks to make a Rock Paper Scissors game where user selects one choice and then `random.randint(0,2)` generates the random choice for computer.

I have already written a working game (Finnish language in variables, functions and prints) :

```
import random

kierrokset = 0
voitot = 0
tasapelit = 0

def arvoTietokone():
    tietokone = random.randint(0,2)
    if tietokone == 0:
        print("tietokone valitsi: Jalka")
        return tietokone
    elif tietokone == 1:
        print("tietokone valitsi: Ydinase")
        return tietokone
    else:
        print("tietokone valitsi: Torakka")
        return tietokone

def arvoVoittaja(pelaaja, tietokone):
    global kierrokset, voitot, tasapelit
    if pelaaja == "Jalka":
        if tietokone == 0:
            print("Tasapeli!")
            tasapelit += 1
            kierrokset += 1

        elif tietokone == 1:
            print("Hävisit!")
            kierrokset += 1

        else:
            print("Voitit!")
            voitot += 1
            kierrokset += 1

    elif pelaaja == "Ydinase":
        if tietokone == 0:
            print("Voitit!")
            voitot += 1
            kierrokset += 1

        elif tietokone == 1:
            print("Tasapeli!")
            tasapelit += 1
            kierrokset += 1

        else:
            print("Hävisit!")
            kierrokset += 1

    elif pelaaja == "Torakka":
        if tietokone == 0:
            print("Hävisit!")
            kierrokset += 1

        elif tietokone == 1:
            print("Voitit!")
            voitot += 1
            kierrokset += 1
        else:
            print("Tasapeli!")
            tasapelit += 1
            kierrokset += 1

while True:

    pelaaja = input("Jalka, Ydinase vai Torakka? (Lopeta lopettaa): ")

    if pelaaja == "Lopeta":
        print("Pelasit",kierrokset,"joista voitit",voitot,"ja pelasit tasan",tasapelit,"peliä.")
        break

    print("Sinä valitsit: ",pelaaja)

    tietokone = arvoTietokone()

    arvoVoittaja(pelaaja, tietokone)
```

I have no problems with code itself, but here's the kicker:

The testing platform that the course uses runs 3 different test runs for the code and each time computer choice has to be exactly different one. On Test1 computer choice has to be Rock, on Test2 computer choice must be Paper, and on Test3 computer choice must be Scissors.

How can you produce the choices exactly in that order (Rock, Paper, Scissors) when the choice is generated on random?

It is as if the task wants 3 specific randoms in specific order.

Is this logically even possible or is the course task invalid/badly designed?

I already have sent feedback to the teacher handling the course, but I have not yet received a response.

Comment: Logically it makes no sense to have a random value that is predefined. Technically it is of course possible e.g. by replacing the "randint" in your code by something else or by calling "random.seed" with an appropriate value (which must be found first) before the actual program runs to manipulate the random generator to be not random. If the program is closed and reopened between the turns it also needs to store state in between in a file.

Comment: Did files or networking feature in your curriculum? Maybe the task does not call for randomness at all, but asks you to store the state of your program in a file. (Alternatively, you could use a network service to store the state, but that's probably out of scope for a homework assignment.)

Comment: @phihag files were studied in earlier chapter, but the platform does not allow external files, it is just one pre-made submission form file that you write the code in and after clicking "execute" the course platform runs tests to check if the code completes the task. We don't submit an actual file from our pc's, the files and everything else runs on the platform server. We just fill the code into the "editor" form. And the task really says "pc choice is generated on random" at the start of the task briefing.

Comment: @MichaelButscher yeah, but the course platform is just a submission field "editor" where we just write the code and then click "execute" to see if it goes through the tests. External files cannot be used, everything like files or tests are run on the platform side. I think the task/course platform has an error in design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I've managed to pass the Python course. Turned out that they have a design error in their course platform and thus this task was logically impossible.